# Testing ternary operator (Angular)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've got a problem with writting a test for ternary expression.

Okay so here is part of my code, it's connected to angular translations and as you can see we have a small ternary expression here. When I run test coverage it highlights `'pl'` with a information: 'Branch not covered'.

What is the best way to cover it in Karma?

```
const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
this.language = browserLang.match(/pl|en/) ? browserLang : 'pl';
translate.use(this.language);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before your test sequence, set up what browser language will be detected. Inject your `TranslateService` in your test as `translate` then create the Spy:

```
spyOn(translate, 'getBrowserLang').and.returnValue('de');
```

This will make sure you will hit the "else" branch in your ternary operator.